# VSTO 4.0 Customized functionality in this program will not work because files cannot be found

Tags: .net, vsto, clickonce

Below there is the full error message which is logged by the event viewer on one of the users' machine:

`Customization URI: file://appdkba1456/a/
Exception: Customized functionality in this program will not work because one or more of the files for the following customization cannot be found: nameOfTheAddin. Uninstall the customization from the Add or Remove Programs dialog box in Control Panel, and then install the customization from the following location: file://appdkba1456/a/nameOfTheAddin.vsto.
************** Exception Text **************
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Deployment.OfflineAddInFailedException: Customized functionality in this program will not work because one or more of the files for the following customization cannot be found: nameOfTheAddin. Uninstall the customization from the Add or Remove Programs dialog box in Control Panel, and then install the customization from the following location: file://appdkba1456/a/nameOfTheAddIn.vsto. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: The system cannot find the file specified. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070002)`

Until now, I was able to find out [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.tools.applications.deployment.offlineaddinfailedexception%28v=vs.90%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) that the `OfflineAddInFailedException` is thrown when the solution is not present inside the ClickOnce cache. Then I have tried to replicate the scenario on my machine by deleting the ClickOnce cache, but I couldn't. In fact what happened was that he cache was rebuild when the add-in started.

What I would like to ask is if you know any causes for why is this happening? I also mention that the add-in worked perfectly for the past months and that no update was made to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message occurs if the files inside the `%localappdata%\assembly` folder and `%localappdata%\apps` folder are deleted or corrupted and if the .vsto add-in installation file is missing from the folder from where the add-in was installed.

What actually happens, is that when the `apps` folder gets deleted, it will try to retrieve the information needed to rebuild itself from the installation path of the AddIn. Hence the issue.

I hope it will help you also guys :)